# Converting nested list with unequal rows to dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have, what I consider to be, a triple-nested list that I want to convert to a dataframe. There is a similar question on here but the difference I have is that my data have unequal row numbers. I do not know how to make a reprex of this complex data with unequal rows so I included a picture of the data structure.

I tried the code below but got the error pasted below it.

```
dfr <- do.call(rbind,lapply(a_local,function(x) as.data.frame.list(lapply(x,as.data.frame.list))))

Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

bind_rows(a_local)

Error: Argument 1 can't be a list containing data frames
```

[image: Screenshot of my dataframes structure]

**Edit: reprex of a similar output below**

```
list(list(`2000` = structure(list(measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", 
"raw alpha"), q = 0:2, type_level = c("types", "types", "types"
), type_name = c("", "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", 
"metacommunity", "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", 
""), diversity = c(130, 47.6362106646841, 29.1304206610839)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2001` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(128, 
    46.3663699146013, 29.0085607409981)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2002` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(112, 
    34.8429465109795, 19.6418918995337)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2003` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(138, 
    36.278539988337, 20.2563354116874)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2004` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(152, 
    41.5585943976923, 24.4257576835118)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2005` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(136, 
    53.0647037177875, 37.9006652475377)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2006` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(142, 
    48.4695259044628, 30.8725886657974)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2007` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(161, 
    52.4982892170671, 33.4245776914158)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2008` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(190, 
    37.6842601161025, 17.1959659030679)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2009` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(177, 
    50.6980919345464, 30.4026099015626)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2010` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(165, 
    33.6759915646318, 16.5874806230282)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2011` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(191, 
    37.967808614851, 16.1793729566448)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(`2000` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(62, 
    25.1734201802724, 16.2717853623945)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2001` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(54, 
    18.6719253089667, 11.2581657586825)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2002` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(56, 
    19.0231843901984, 11.0947252228356)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2003` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(57, 
    22.8282386416829, 12.5165034323462)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2004` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(51, 
    30.8105815978442, 22.1295834457466)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2005` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(50, 
    33.9034098784768, 26.4879053020106)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2006` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(62, 
    33.7190440665969, 22.2146972715582)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2007` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(72, 
    39.0907734308199, 21.7383249141099)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2008` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(79, 
    41.1438272519128, 27.8199767081214)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2009` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(72, 
    38.7526553238673, 23.7441284758299)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2010` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(66, 
    32.6248446686476, 19.6259433905257)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2011` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(68, 
    41.3940021837551, 30.5861687624241)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(`2002` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(38, 
    10.278518823847, 5.95517798951935)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2003` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(38, 
    12.9546999522406, 7.32849312366838)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2006` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(37, 
    17.7209870045672, 12.4870099104185)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2007` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(40, 
    17.1610003189147, 10.3260620890448)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2008` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(53, 
    26.3148331651736, 17.1659824860019)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2009` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(47, 
    11.9312680860448, 5.41945336689468)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2011` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(45, 
    6.01237181210209, 2.42710546694491)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(`2000` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(47, 
    16.0537839386773, 9.15401148634299)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2001` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(39, 
    14.0891052780818, 7.4340030245741)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2002` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(40, 
    19.9182625826876, 11.8134371553591)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2003` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(50, 
    22.5388076466994, 12.0191726459901)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2004` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(43, 
    24.2223797494203, 14.892217206058)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2006` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(36, 
    22.8858413683323, 14.3488216613739)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2007` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(57, 
    9.14200541985277, 3.11306568929166)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2008` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(48, 
    7.63659000253928, 2.66521736760175)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2009` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(48, 
    8.3410364450592, 3.27251065971041)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2010` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(58, 
    13.9406660758292, 4.74839528806686)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2011` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(54, 
    11.1318665817255, 3.58610226121249)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(`2000` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(33, 
    16.6294253666135, 11.176343410935)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2001` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(30, 
    16.4347026429985, 12.077846009268)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2002` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(34, 
    17.3684052590679, 12.6615910826356)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2003` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(39, 
    17.2957608108924, 10.6444628801781)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2004` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(29, 
    16.1566079338594, 11.9277978772552)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2006` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(37, 
    18.894306584847, 12.3929163117495)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2007` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(47, 
    23.4879074697119, 15.4293690573247)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2008` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(46, 
    21.1396265765405, 12.6772679784588)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2010` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(46, 
    24.5337325449747, 16.7574484292759)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2011` = structure(list(
    measure = c("raw alpha", "raw alpha", "raw alpha"), q = 0:2, 
    type_level = c("types", "types", "types"), type_name = c("", 
    "", ""), partition_level = c("metacommunity", "metacommunity", 
    "metacommunity"), partition_name = c("", "", ""), diversity = c(58, 
    25.500304964892, 14.2651685427877)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))))
```

The desired dataframe output would be something like

```
  ID (as list#)      measure  q  diversity   Year
   1                    alpha 0 0.97279      2000       
   1                    alpha 1  0.87381     2000       
   1                    alpha 2  0.10823     2000       
   1                    beta 0  0.55075      2000       
   1                    beta 1  0.01355      2000       
   1                    beta 2  0.10672      2000       
   1                    gamma 0  0.55075     2000       
   1                    gamma 1  0.01355     2000       
   1                    gamma 2  0.10672     2000       
   1                    alpha 0  0.1136      2001
```

and then on to the next year until the next first-grouping-list comes. Does that makes sense?

Comment: yeah, you are right from the image it seems a daunting task

Comment: i added another output that has a similar structure but was more manageable for dput!

Comment: So what do you expect as expected `data.frame` output? Please include that in your post.

Comment: I added the output the best I could. Does it make sense? variations of it are fine, I just really would like to understand how to combine these dfs together

Comment: @jabbys I'm not able to copy-paste the data into RStudio, it returns _type\_level function(...)_ in the Global Env.

Comment: @A.Suliman yeah, I have the same problem. I tried another dput output but it was the same and still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the dput output of the nested list won't vectorize into an object when pasted into R. But I am not trying to solve that!

I figured out the proper way to get this into the desired format!

```
out <- lapply(nested_list, function(x) 
    do.call("rbind", x))
bind_rows(out, .id = "column_label")

# A tibble: 156 x 8
   column_label measure       q type_level type_name partition_level partition_name diversity
   <chr>        <chr>     <int> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>           <chr>              <dbl>
 1 1            raw alpha     0 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                 130  
 2 1            raw alpha     1 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                  47.6
 3 1            raw alpha     2 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                  29.1
 4 1            raw alpha     0 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                 128  
 5 1            raw alpha     1 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                  46.4
 6 1            raw alpha     2 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                  29.0
 7 1            raw alpha     0 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                 112  
 8 1            raw alpha     1 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                  34.8
 9 1            raw alpha     2 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                  19.6
10 1            raw alpha     0 types      ""        metacommunity   ""                 138
```